# Should users reputation be hidden when they first answer questions?

Tags: discussion, subjective, stackexchange

This is highly subjective, but I've noticed that as my reputation has increased I seem to get slightly more upvotes.  There are lots of possible explanations for this, but I wonder if people are more likely to upvote answers from people with higher reputations.  I'm fairly sure that at least sub-consciously I give more weight to such answers.

This is obviously a good thing when you come to look back at an old question, but I wonder if hiding the reputation of an answerer for the first (say) 24 hours might lead to more representative voting?

Has this been tried on any other stack exchange sites?

Comment: I think it would be a pretty good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been discussed before on Meta Stack Overflow. I can't find the specific question, but a search for ["hide reputation"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=hide+reputation) gives 24 results.

These three questions:

[Should there be anonymous answers (and questions)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198/should-there-be-anonymous-answers-and-questions)

[Should reputation be hidden until an answer is accepted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79621/should-reputation-be-hidden-until-an-answer-is-accepted)

[Hide the rep and badge count on a user's info box on answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21458/hide-the-rep-and-badge-count-on-a-users-info-box-on-answers)

Are closest to what you're asking

Comment: Thanks, I'd looked on here, but hadn't though to look for a meta.stackexchange.

It seems like there was some general mild enthusiasm for the idea, but no official comment either way.  Should I assume that the stackexchange team have considered and dismissed the idea?

Comment: @LukeGraham - probably ;)